# Stretch divs and pictures to fill full section id, section id="Matches" is issue

Tags: html, css

I have been following an online course and cant get a group of articles to stretch out to fill the full 1000px allocated for each section ID. I could add in more text but this is a quick fix and would prefer to know of a beter solution that can be used in future. I would like both "Players and Matches" section to fully utilize the full 1000px allocated. This is also my first attempt at HTML/CSS so any other tips or fixes that are spotted would be great to know.

Attempted numerous changes on the classes and id's in the CSS file.

HTML

```
            <article>
                <div class="player-image" style="background:url(data:image/)"></div>
                <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadio_Man%C3%A9"><h3>Sadio Mane</h3></a>
                <p>Europe's hottest winger goes into the final in red hot form<p>
            </article>

            <article>
                <div class="player-image" style="background:url(data:image/)"></div>
                <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohamed_Salah"><h3>Mohamed Salah</h3></a>
                <p>Our record breaking forward finds form at the ideal time<p>
            </article>

            <article>
                <div class="player-image" style="background:url(data:image/)"></div>
                <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgil_van_Dijk"><h3>Virgil Van Dijk</h3></a>
                <p>The man mountain destined to shut out Spurs in the final<p>
            </article>
                    <br /><br />

        </section>

        <section id="Matches">
            <article>
                <div class="game-image" style="background:url(data:image/)"> </div>
                <h3>Liverpool 4 - 0 Barcelona</h3>
                <p> blaaaaaaaaaa... <a href="#" class ="more-link">more...</a>
            </article>

            <article>
                <div class="game-image" style="background:url()"></div>
                <h3>Liverpool 2 - 0 Spurs</h3>
                <p> blaaaaaaaaaa... <a href="#" class ="more-link">more...</a>
            </article>

            <article>
                <div class="game-image" style="background:url(data:image/)"></div>
                <h3>Liverpool 5 - 1 Arsenal</h3>
                <p> blaaaaaaaaaa... <a href="#" class ="more-link">more...</a>
            </article>

        </section>
```

CSS

```
article {
    max-width:30%;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    transition: box-shadow 1500ms;
    }

article img{
    max-width:100%;
}

#Players{
    width: 1000px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    text-align:center;
    }

#Matches{
    width: 1000px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items:stretch;
    }

.Player{
    text-align:center;

}

.player-image {
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background-size:cover !important;
    background-position:center !important;
    border:0px solid transparent;
    border-radius:25%;
}

.game-image {
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background-size:cover !important;
    background-position:center !important;
    border:0px solid transparent;
    border-radius:25%;
```

Comment: if the parent elements for Players and Matches are set to 1000px, then setting `width: 100%;` on both Players and Matches should make them take up the full space

Answer (score 0):

flex-grow: 1; - make items to take up all available space evenly across main axis